# Android 13 Update Causing Notification and Deep Linking Issues in Existing Apps

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, version

**Question:**

I recently updated my Android device to Android 13, and I've noticed that some of my existing apps are experiencing issues related to notifications and deep linking. These apps were working perfectly fine before the update, but now I'm encountering problems.

**Notifications:** Some apps are not delivering notifications as they used to. I've checked the notification settings, and they seem to be configured correctly. Is there anything specific about Android 13 that might be causing this issue? Are there any changes in the way notifications are handled in Android 13 that I need to be aware of?

**Deep Linking:** Several apps that used deep linking to open specific content or activities are no longer working as expected. When I click on a deep link, nothing happens, or I'm redirected to the app's main screen instead of the intended content. Has Android 13 introduced changes to deep linking behavior that might be causing this problem? Are there any new considerations for handling deep links in Android 13?

I'd appreciate any insights, tips, or guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve these issues. Additionally, if there are any known changes or updates related to notifications and deep linking in Android 13, please provide that information.

**Device Information:**

Android Version: Android 13

Before posting this question, I attempted the following steps to troubleshoot the issues with notifications and deep linking on Android 13:

Notifications:

Checked App Notification Settings: I verified that the affected apps had their notification settings properly configured in Android's system settings. All notification channels were enabled.
Deep Linking:

Verified Deep Link Implementation: I reviewed the deep link implementation within the affected apps to ensure that it was correctly defined in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
Tested Deep Links with Sample URLs: I tested deep links with sample URLs to verify that the URIs were correctly formatted and matched the app's intent filters.
However, despite these efforts, I still encountered the mentioned issues. Here's what I was expecting:

Notifications:

I expected that the apps' notifications would work seamlessly on Android 13, just as they did on previous Android versions.
Deep Linking:

I expected that clicking on a deep link associated with a specific app's content would open that content or activity directly within the app, rather than redirecting me to the app's main screen.